# D-lang being faster than C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, d

So I was practising for an upcoming programming contest on algorithms, and I stumbled upon a problem from the previous year.

I pretty much solved it(in C++), but i was getting some timeouts, so i took a look at the official solution and it was written in Dlang.

I then tried to imitate what the official answer did in D, but I was still getting timeouts( > 4 seconds on a single input). Afaik, C++ is supposed to be faster than D, but D solves the same input in a split second and C++ takes more than 5 seconds for it

Here is the D answer code

```
import std.stdio;
import std.algorithm;

struct edge {
    int src, des, w, o;

    int opCmp (ref const edge e) const {
        if(w != e.w) return w - e.w;
        else return o - e.o;
    }
};

const int MAXN = 100004, MAXM = 200004;
int N, M, D, ee, weight, days;
int[MAXN] ds;
edge[] edges;

void init() {
    for(int i=1;i<=N;i++) ds[i] = i;
}

int find(int x) {
    return ds[x] = (x == ds[x] ? x: find(ds[x]));
}

bool connected(int x, int y) {
    return find(x) == find(y);
}

bool merge(int x, int y) {
    int xr = find(x), yr = find(y);
    if(xr ^ yr) {
        ds[xr] = yr;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void main() {
    scanf("%d%d%d", &N, &M, &D);
    for(int i=1, a, b, c;i<=M;i++) {
        scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
        if(i < N)
            edges ~= edge(a, b, c, 0);
        else
            edges ~= edge(a, b, c, 1);
    }
    edges.sort();
    init();
    int i, maxe=0;
    for(i=0;i<edges.length;i++) {
        auto e = edges[i];
        if(merge(e.src, e.des)) {
            if(e.o)
                days ++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", days);
}
```

And then here is what I wrote in C++ as the answer code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Edge{
    long long source, end, weight, old;
    Edge(long long _s, long long _e, long long _w, long long _o):source(_s), end(_e), weight(_w), old(_o){}
};

int parents[100004];
vector<Edge>edges;

bool inc(Edge a, Edge b)
{
    if(a.weight == b.weight)return a.old > b.old;
    return a.weight < b.weight;
}

long long find(long long node)
{
    if(parents[node] == node)return node;
    else return find(parents[node]);
}

void init(long long M)
{
    for(long long i = 0; i < M; ++i)parents[i] = i;
}

bool connect(long long x, long long y)
{
    long long fx = find(x);
    long long fy = find(y);
    if(fx == fy)return false;
    parents[fx] = fy;
    return true;
}

long long noOfDays()
{
    long long days = 0;
    for(auto edge : edges){
        if(connect(edge.source, edge.end)){
            if(!edge.old)++days;
        }
    }
    return days;
}

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false); 
    long long N, M , D;
    cin >> N >> M >> D;
    N--;
    for(long long i = 0; i < M; ++i){
        long long a,b,c;
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        if(i < N){
            edges.push_back(Edge(a,b,c,1));
        }else{
            edges.push_back(Edge(a,b,c,0));         
        }
    }
    sort(edges.begin(), edges.end(), inc);
    init(N+2);
    cout << noOfDays() << endl;
}
```

The input which takes more than 5 seconds on C++, and a split second on D can be found here "http://ddl3.data.hu/get/356808/10699419/s4.24.in"

Here is the question I was actually trying to solve "https://dmoj.ca/problem/ccc17s4"(I am only doing the 11 point part).

Is there any way I can make my C++ code as fast as the D code? and why exactly isn't my C++ code running as fast as the D code?

---

EDIT: For all clarifications, g++ was used for the C++ without any optimizations, and 'dmd' for the Dlang, without any optimizations either

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations on?

Comment: It's possible that the site has different time limits for C++ and D.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to perform some profiling to see where the bottlenecks are in the C++ code.

Comment: @Mandy - for c++: `edges.reserve(M)` before `for(...`? And `edges.emplace_back()` instead of `edges.push_back()`?

Comment: why are your snippets so different? different flow of logic? different names? makes it hard to compare why one would be faster than the other...

Comment: I would downvote just on that we have no idea which compiler was used, what optimaztions were used, etc (all requirements if we're going to compare speed of a program).

Comment: @Mandy - important for c++: the signature for `inc()` should be `bool inc(Edge const & a, Edge const & b)`; this can avoid a lot of unuseful copies.

Comment: `for(auto edge : edges){` also creates copies.

Comment: Instead of taking solutions written for one language, you should carefully inspect what you're doing.  For example, your `find` function is recursive, and with all of that data, potentially blowing out the call stack.  You should rewrite this to be iterative -- not only will you save on stack space, the unwinding of the stack also won't be done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find()` seems to be heavily used and they are very different in D and C++ implementations:

```
int find(int x) {
    return ds[x] = (x == ds[x] ? x: find(ds[x]));
}
```

vs:

```
long long find(long long node)
{
    if(parents[node] == node)return node;
    else return find(parents[node]);
}
```

`find()` in D modifies array (looks like some kind of dynamic programming, were you cash previous result) while in C++ you always do full lookup. You should compare apples to apples, especially this code could be written exactly the same way in C++.

Comment: (Making previous results available for reuse should most probably read *cache*.)

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity, I tried running OPs code, and also the version below, which I created by minimally tweaking the 'D' code so that it would compile under C++. OPs C++ version took around 12 seconds to run. The version below took around 0.25 seconds to run.

My conclusion, in answer to the question is that the difference in run time seen by the OP is likely due to differences in implementation as described in some of the other answers, as opposed to poor performance of C++.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct edge {
    edge(int src, int des, int w, int o) : src(src), des(des), w(w), o(o) {}

    int src, des, w, o;

    int opCmp(const edge& e) const {
        if (w != e.w) return w - e.w;
        else return o - e.o;
    }
};

const int MAXN = 100004, MAXM = 200004;
int N, M, D, ee, weight, days;
int ds[MAXN];
std::vector<edge> edges;

void init() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) ds[i] = i;
}

int find(int x) {
    return ds[x] = (x == ds[x] ? x : find(ds[x]));
}

bool connected(int x, int y) {
    return find(x) == find(y);
}

bool merge(int x, int y) {
    int xr = find(x), yr = find(y);
    if (xr ^ yr) {
        ds[xr] = yr;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void main() {
    std::scanf("%d%d%d", &N, &M, &D);
    for (int i = 1, a, b, c; i <= M; i++) {
        scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
        if (i < N)
            edges.push_back(edge(a, b, c, 0));
        else
            edges.push_back(edge(a, b, c, 1));
    }
    std::sort(edges.begin(), edges.end(), [](const edge& lhs, const edge& rhs) { return lhs.opCmp(rhs) < 0; });
    init();
    int i, maxe = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<edges.size(); i++) {
        auto e = edges[i];
        if (merge(e.src, e.des)) {
            if (e.o)
                days++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", days);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible contributor to the slow performance of the C++ version is the 'inc' function. It receives 2 'Edge' structs by value, which in C++ will mean copying of the structs for every comparison during the sort call towards the end of main().

Try changing the signature of 'inc' to accept 'const Edge&' instead of 'Edge'. This will cause the struct values to be passed by reference and so avoid the extra copying.

Also, if you run a profiler you should be able to find where the majority of the time is being spent. This is the 'right' way to approach optimization: measure to find where you have a performance bottleneck, address the bottleneck and measure again to confirm you have indeed improved the performance.

Comment: I doubt this would make so big difference